# Google Analytics: 100% Drop off from landing page

Tags: google-analytics

I have a Web site built in Drupal 7 - we'll call it website.com.  Outside of that site, I have a campaign specific landing page - we'll call that website.com/landingpage.  On this page, there are a couple of buttons back to the main website (website.com).  I have goals set up that track a user from that landing page, back to the main site home page, then through a few other steps.  for some reason, even though I know users are clicking through to the site, I'm getting a 100% drop-off from the landing page to the main site...

...anyone have any thoughts as to why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a dynamic webapp? Is the routing is handled in the client and not on the server side?

If it is a dynamic webapp and routing is handled in the client, then GA won't track your pageviews automatically, and you have to do it manually. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications

If you are using angularjs you can use this great tool:
http://luisfarzati.github.io/angulartics/