# Google Analytics: Visitors flow: Only showing root with 100% drop off, no pages

Tags: google-analytics, visitors

I would like to use the google analytics visitors flow tool but it does not show any specific page. All visits are in one big block "/". If I click on "group details" pages are listed just fine.

My site uses url parameters like mypage.com?p=products to switch between pages. I have managed to set up analytics so that it understands this and works on the "content" page and everywhere. How can I make it also work with "visitors flow" to display specific pages?

this might be the same problem: [Google Analytics: 100% Drop off from landing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111783/google-analytics-100-drop-off-from-landing-page)

Just noticed that links on my page are missing the slash before the "?". will add the slash and report back.

Edit: Though I guess that was an improvement it did not solve the problem.
I am using absolute links (http:/mysite.com/?p=contact) all over the place. Should I try relative links to get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to put a / before the ? in your links or else Analytics could interpret your full URL as the domain/sub-domain and not report any page paths or levels (like you're observing).

Additionally, are you sure the Analytics script is firing whenever a new page is loaded? Clicking through your site it looks like the base page template may not be reloading whenever you click to a different page (only the content is reloaded). If this is the case and the Analytics script is part of your base template, it would only fire once when the visitor first enters the site and load the page template and never again. Since Google Analytics calculates pageviews and time on site/page based on the difference in time between when the _trackPageview() is fired, it could explain your problem.

I would suggest moving your Analytics script to a portion of the markup that is reloaded every time someone clicks to a new page to see if this does the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not make a difference.

Comment: Looked through your site and edited my previous answer with another possible cause of the problem here.

Comment: While it would certainly explain the problem if only the content of the page would be reloaded it is not the case. The whole output of the index.php file is reloaded every time (I even checked with firebug).